# Change xmlns:wsse namespace in SOAP request with Python Zeep

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, xml-namespaces, zeep

When using Zeep (Python3.7) to send data to a SOAP API, the `wsse:Security` header generated is `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd`

The result of this is the error:

```
zeep.exceptions.Fault: SOAP Security Header UsernameToken is required for operation 'ProcessMessage'
```

If I then take the raw request XML and send that to the API (via SOAPUI), I get the same issue. However, if I change this value to the value that was in the example I've been sent alongside the WSDL of `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext`, the request completes successfully and I get a success response from the API.

I have tried many things, including explicitely defining the namespace in Security element header:

```
header = xsd.Element(
    '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext}Security',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            'UsernameToken',
            xsd.ComplexType([
                xsd.Element('Username', xsd.String()),
                xsd.Element('Password', xsd.String()),
            ])
        )
    ])
)
```

However, this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

I've also tried:

```py
client.set_default_soapheaders([header_value])
```

Again, no joy.

Is there a way of doing this within Zeep (I'm open to a different SOAP package, although Zeep seemed the most actively maintained)? Or am I missing something in my request format entirely that could be causing this issue?

Code below. Thank you in advance!

```py
header = xsd.Element(
    'Security',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            'UsernameToken',
            xsd.ComplexType([
                xsd.Element('Username', xsd.String()),
                xsd.Element('Password', xsd.String()),
            ])
        )
    ])
)

header_value = header(UsernameToken={'Username': user, 'Password': password})

client.service.ProcessMessage(_soapheaders=[header_value], Payload=dataobj)
```

In terms of generated XML, the above example gives the following:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
      ### REQUEST BODY
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Which does not work

However, by simply changing the `wsse:Security xmlns:wsse` value to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext` in the raw XML and pasting that into SOAPUI, that works.

Answer (score 1):

Took me 2 days but found fix for this.
take

```
header = xsd.Element(
'{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext}Security',
xsd.ComplexType([
    xsd.Element(
        'UsernameToken',
        xsd.ComplexType([
            xsd.Element('Username', xsd.String()),
            xsd.Element('Password', xsd.String()),
        ])
    )
])
```

)

and then add the name space URL info like this to all attributes not just the group

```
  header = xsd.Element(
'{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext}Security',
xsd.ComplexType([
    xsd.Element(
        '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext}UsernameToken',
        xsd.ComplexType([
            xsd.Element('{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext}Username', xsd.String()),
            xsd.Element('{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext}Password', xsd.String()),
        ])
    )
])
```

)

also make sure you put the name space on the client like this

```
client.set_ns_prefix('wsse', "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
```

Comment: Great answer, saved my day. In `ns.py`, `zzep` has hardcoded the WSSE URI and thereafter a SOAP server built from gSOAP was rejecting that - I had no option but to populate the headers myself.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by switching to using a different SOAP library.

Comment: What library did you end up using? what worked for you?